# What is the minimum text of birkat hamazon one needs to say to be yotze?

Tags: rambam, bentching

Let's say you're in the army or something and need to bench quickly and be on your way. Is there a "havineinu" equivalent for benching (beyond just stopping after the fourth bracha) that you could use b'shaas had'chak?  I've heard the rambams nusach of it was very short, only one paragraph which mentions the themes of each of the 4 brachos. Could this be used - or even just saying in English "thank you God for sustaining us, eretz yisrael, yerushalayim and being a" tov u'meitiv"? Is so, should the full version of benching be said later on, assuming you're still within the time frame to bench?

Comment: See OC 191. In certain cases you can combine the second and third blessings and skip the fourth entirely.

Comment: Rav Abadi and Rav Henkin have made abridged versions either for children or ppl who cant do the whole thing

Comment: See Rambam Hilkhot Berakhot 2:2. See also the abridgements of Rassag, and Rav Abadi.

Comment: @sam that's the full four in just a shorter nusach, not a proper havinenu style combination

Comment: I recall seeing in a _sidur_ a version described as being for women that matches what you seek. I hope I can remember what _sidur_ I saw it in.

Comment: What @sam is mentioning, i.e. for children, is called brich: "Brich Rachamana Malka d'alma ma'rei d'hai pita" ("Blessed is The Compassionate One, Ruler of the universe, Source of this food"), then "Brich Rachamana d'zan kulo" ("Blessed is The Compassionate One, Who nourishes the entire world"). Supposedly it replaces both a fore- and after- blessing, though I have no idea how permissible any of this is for those over 8

Comment: I don't think anyone would say we can substitute these short things for bentching l'chatchila, but here is something else I have found: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wiq5jzwV38I